# Createprocess and 0xc0000142 error

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

i have the following test code:

```
#define CMDLINE ".\\dummyFolder\\dummyProc.exe op1 op2 op3"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

STARTUPINFO info;
info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
info.lpReserved = NULL;
info.cbReserved2 = 0;
info.lpReserved2 = NULL;

PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES procAttr;
procAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
procAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
procAttr.bInheritHandle = false;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttr;
procAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
procAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
procAttr.bInheritHandle = false;

bool handlersInheritable = true;

char cmdLine2[sizeof(CMDLINE)];
strcpy(cmdLine2, CMDLINE);

char AppName[sizeof(".\\dummyFolder\\dummyProc.exe")];
strcpy(AppName, ".\\dummyFolder\\dummyProc.exe");


if (CreateProcess(AppName, cmdLine2, &procAttr, &threadAttr,
        handlersInheritable, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)) {

    //::WaitForMultipleObjects(procQty, handlers, waitForAll, waitInterval);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(info.hStdError);
    CloseHandle(info.hStdInput);
    CloseHandle(info.hStdOutput);
} else {
    std::cout << "Returned: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "Exiting main process" << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

This is just a test code for creating processes in windows. The problem is that when i launch "dummyProc.exe" i get a 0xc0000142 error.

The process dummyProc.exe runs fine from the command line, but not from within the code.

Here's the dummyProc code if it helps:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {


std::cout << "Working!!!!" << std::endl << "Receivedi: " << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;


return 0;
}
```

So, any ideas?

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960266

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious thing that `char cmdLine2[sizeof(CMDLINE)];` declares a string of length equal to your machine's pointer size. You need to use `strlen(CMDLINE)+1` instead. Likewise for `appName`.

Note that the first parameter to `CreateProcess` does not need to be writeable. Just pass the string literal directly to it. No need for `appName` variable.

As for `lpCommandLine` which does need to be writeable it's easiest to do it like this:

```
char cmdline[] = "op1 op2 op3";
```

That gives you a writeable buffer. Note that you do not need to repeat the executable file  name.

Another problem is  that you have not initialized all the parameters to `CreateProcess`. For example the `STARTUPINFO` struct has 19 fields and you initialize only 3. You should initialize all your structs to 0 and then fill out any fields you need to be non-zero. Like this:

```
STARTUPINFO info = { 0 };
```

Do this for all the structs you pass.

You can, and should, pass `NULL` for the `lpProcessAttributes` and `lpThreadAttributes` parameters.

Comment: Not initializing all bytes of `STARTUPINFO` will result in **every** process exit with code as `0xC0000142` immediately - even for `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`. Overlooked this culprit for hours. It's like the OS wants you to fail when you don't work properly.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is to relate another cause for `0xc0000142` - placed here (even though another answer was accepted for this question) because there is very little useful information on the intertubes about this error - and a shocking *lack* of *any* useful information on the subject from Microsoft - and so someone's internet search may get them here.  (Well, mine did.)

So:  You can get `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)` on starting a process written in C++ where you access though a null pointer in a constructor of a static object.  (In my case it was in an initializer of a constructor of a static object.)

Your hint to this will be an event in the application log (event id 1000 source "Application Error") which has lines similar to the following:

```
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000000000
```

`0xc0000005` is access violation, of course, and the offset of 0 (actually anything less than `0x10000` is a reference through a null pointer.

Anyway, the surprising thing (to me) is that evaluating statics happens *before* the debugger can attach (!!) so launching it with `ImageFileExecutionOptions` set or even directly within Visual Studio doesn't let you debug this thing!!

(And then of course you won't find `0xc0000142` in any Microsoft documentation whatsoever.  Well done, NT team!)

Comment: That NTSTATUS is documented as STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED